# How to disable scrolling in web browser in wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My objective is to disable the scrolling action in my web browser control without using IsHitTestVisible as false.To click on links I need it to as true.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<WebBrowser Height="100" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```